# ctags/vim - Trouble handling expressions with brackets in identifier list

Tags: regex, bash, vim, exuberant-ctags

I'm using vim with ctags (exuberant 5.7) to navigate my source code. Some of the functions and variables have some Intel C extension keywords added to them however, namely:

```
__declspec(target(mic)) double calculate_gamma(int m, int n) { ... }
```

The problem is that because of the __declspec the ctags neglects to index it so the function calculate_gamma doesn't get tagged.

The fix to this sort of thing with ctags you use the identifier list option -I. However this options hates you if your expression has brackets in it:

```
$ ctags *.c *.h -I __declspec(target(mic))
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I've tried putting quotation marks around __declspec, escape characters '\', and ansi-C quoting $'' and these all stop bash from complaining, but then ctags still doesn't tag the function calculate_gamma. If the brackets weren't there this would work.

What am I doing wrong or is there another way to get what I want out of ctags? Cheers.

Comment: The man page says you can append `+` to make it ignore the brackets but it doesn't work for me ... `ctags *.[ch] -I __declspec+`.

Comment: You can try to put the exceptions into a file, and then supply the filename to the -I option like: **-I ./my_exceptions.txt** .. Though I could not get ctags (exuberant ctags 5.8) to set the functionname to **calculate_gamma** .. the function was always named **target** in the resulting tags file. But the resulting regexp was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
ctags -I __declspec+ *.c *.h
```

The `-I __declspec` essentially tells ctags to ignore `__declspec` as if it were a macro, and the `+` suffix means to also ignore the parenthesized arguments which follow `__declspec`.